# How can I provide a 2-way mirror of a Git repository with another SCM? (bzr, hg etc)

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs, bazaar

For the last 6 months or so I've been using a 2-way Git mirror of our main Perforce repository at work to evaluate it for our workflow.  I have to say I've fallen in love with using it but it has had one fatal flaw for me so far: it's Windows support is terrible.

Generally this is not an issue for me but right now it is.  I need to do some work on some locally committed work in my Git repo and I cannot get to it from the machine I need to work on as there are some unsolvable issues with the Git distro on this box.

Anyhow, what I want to do if I can is to run a second mirror: this time piggy-backing off of my Git repository but serving via Mercurial or Bazar.  I've found a few tools that look promising and some references in blog comments saying that people have done this but nothing complete.

So can anyone tell me if there is a simple way to maintain a 2-way mirror to a Git repository using another DVCS that *will* work on Windows without any trouble?

Thanks in advance for your troubles...

Jamie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A new option has popped up on the scene from the folks over at GitHub: [git-hg](http://hg-git.github.com/).  Now there's a way to do a two-way sync between Git and Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

I know that Mercurial has an extension that will let you convert from git to mercurial.
More on https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension

I haven't used it myself though.

Comment: I had a go with this last night: it doesn't convert the history from Git in a usable way, it merges all branches into the default branch due to the way Git treats branches internally.  I need something I can do a reasonable two-way mirror with.

Comment: Points going here since it's the only answer that actually addresses the question I asked!  Others might also like to look up "Taylor" which can help too...

Comment: Convert is strictly one-way.  It's not the synchronization tool for which he's looking.

Answer (score 3):

[*wikified since this isn't really an answer*]

I'm using [MSYS git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) without problems on Vista. I do host my git repos on a Debian GNU/Linux box though.

Comment: The problem I have with Git on Windows is to do with the Windows box I use:  It's a 64bit Windows 2008 install running on a KVM linux host as a VM. I've tried both Msys Git and cygwin:

• Msys doesnt work on Windows 2008 64bit (knownbug)
• Cygwin exposes bug in KVM.

If I could I would!

Comment: Well, for anyone interested, I *finally* found a fix to the issue I had with msys Git: See [here for details][1]


  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=122&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: Wow! What a pain. Congrats for finding a solution though!

Answer (score 2):

bzr has fast-import plugin, so you will be able to create 2-way conversion using fast-export/fast-import pair: http://bazaar-vcs.org/BzrFastImport

Answer (score 1):

There's also [tailor](http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor) that allows mirroring between several repositories. I had it working on Cygwin with quite some success -- until someone added files that made the command line svn choke; though that might be a rather rare problem to hit.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial has probably the best support for Windows (out of git & bzr).  It even has a TortoiseHg extension [here](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/).

Comment: Mercurial is my preferred mirror but the question is how to create a 2-way Git / Mercurial mirror...if you know please do tell! Txs.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're not likely to find a satisfactory solution with the currently available git to other DVCS synchronization tools.  You could probably cobble together a workable system using [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) to go from get to subversion and [hgsubversion](http://code.google.com/p/hgsubversion/) to synchronize between mercurial and subversion, but that seems like a crazy kludge just to get around weak git support on windows.

Perhaps you'd be better off emailing diffs from the windows box -- git has excellent email-patch-handling support (as does mercurial).